# Change attachment filename

Tags: attachments

Is there a function that allows me to change the filename of an attachment, based on the Attachment ID I have?

Thanks!
Dennis

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This will allow you to rename an attachment as soon as its uploaded:

```
add_action('add_attachment', 'rename_attachment');
function rename_attachment($post_ID){

    $file = get_attached_file($post_ID);
    $path = pathinfo($file);
        //dirname   = File Path
        //basename  = Filename.Extension
        //extension = Extension
        //filename  = Filename

    $newfilename = "NEW FILE NAME HERE";
    $newfile = $path['dirname']."/".$newfilename.".".$path['extension'];

    rename($file, $newfile);    
    update_attached_file( $post_ID, $newfile );

}
```

Comment: very precisely explained :)

Comment: uhm, I get this rename(): http wrapper does not support renaming

Comment: There is a typo here. The function should be called `rename_attachment`.

Comment: I think for clarity is better if you name $post_ID as $attach_ID or something similar, because it could be confused with the parent post ID, while it's meant to be the attachment ID. Good anwser :)

Comment: Please notice this doesn't change the attachment guid, so the code relying on the guid to get the image source for instance won't work. Although generally speaking you shouldn't change a post guid, in this situation could be wise to update the guid as well.

Comment: Make also sure to run `wp_generate_attachment_metadata()` afterwards so that all thumbnails will be re-generated properly.

Answer (score 4):

#### Use Cases

The function works for

- Adding files
- Updating files (yes, also for files that are already present)
- Multiple files

#### No-Use Cases

It aborts for autosave jobs, performed by wordpress automagically or if the targeted file types or mime types are not met.

#### Goodies

You can set the file name, file types & mime types that you want to change inside the 
function before the `foreach` loop. The file gets the post ID and then the attachment ID appended, so you can safely upload and change multiple files at a time. This also cares about ordering the files by (first) post ID and (second) attachment ID.

```
function wpse30313_update_attachment_names($post_ID)
{
    // Abort if WP does an autosave 
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return;

    # >>>> SET
        // New file name:
        $new_file_name = "___";

        // Best would be to take the post name as file name instead of a custom title:
        # $post_data = get_post( $post_ID );
        # $new_file_name = $post_data->post_name;

        // The file types we want be changed:
        $allowed_types = array(
            'image'
        );

        // The mime types we want to be changed:
        $allowed_ext = array(
             'jpg'
            ,'jpeg'
            ,'gif'
            ,'png'
        );
    # <<<< SET

    // Appended by post ID for collision safety
    $new_file_name = "{$new_file_name}-{$post_ID}";

    // get all attached files
    $attachments = get_children( array( 
         'post_type'    => 'attachment'
        ,'post_parent'  => $post_ID
    ) );

    // Bulk updating attached file names
    foreach ( $attachments as $att )
    {
        $att_ID     = $att->ID;
        // Append attachment ID (collision safety)
        // Also allows sorting files by post & then attchment ID
        $new_name   = "{$new_file_name}-{$att_ID}";

        $mime_type  = explode( "/", get_post_mime_type( $att->ID ) );
        $file_type  = $mime_type[0];
        $mime_type  = $mime_type[1];

        // Skip file types we don't want to change
        if ( ! in_array( $file_type, $allowed_types ) )
            continue;
        // Skip mime types we don't want to change
        if ( ! in_array( $mime_type, $allowed_ext ) )
            continue;

        // Get current file info
        $file_path = get_attached_file( $att->ID );
        $path   = pathinfo( $file_path );
        $dir    = trailingslashit( $path['dirname'] );
        $ext    = $path['extension'];

        // Build final name
        $final  = "{$dir}{$new_name}.{$ext}";

        // Skip if the path was already changed on upload
        // If we don't set this, the function wouldn't work for older files
        if ( $file_path == $final )
            continue;

        // Update attachment-post meta info for file
        rename( $file_path, $final );
        update_attached_file( $att_ID, $final );
    }

    return;
}
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'wpse30313_update_attachment_names' );
add_action( 'edit_attachment', 'wpse30313_update_attachment_names' );
```

*The function should be added to your functions.php file or (better) as a separate small plugin. Just add a plugin comment on top, upload it to the plugins folder and activate.*

Comment: thank you for the detailed reply, i ran the code and it seemed to execute, but i'm not sure if it changed anything. Should it change the post_name or guid of the attachment object?

Answer (score 3):

I'd use PHP's [`rename`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.rename.php) and the path to the file given by [`get_attached_file`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_file).

```
function rename_file( $post_id, $newname ) {
    $file = get_attached_file( $post_id );
    rename($file,dirname($file).$newname)
}
```

NOTE that this has been not tested and you should extreme precaution when working whith files. It probably needs changing for it to work but may be a good starting point. Hope this helps.

Let me know if it helps and I'll change the code to the actual working code.

Comment: This breaks WordPress's link to the file, since WordPress won't understand that a rename has happened.

Answer (score 3):

```
add_action('add_attachment', 'rename');
function rename($post_ID){

    $post = get_post($post_ID);
    $file = get_attached_file($post_ID);
    $path = pathinfo($file);
    $newfilename = "mynewfilename";
    $newfile = $path['dirname']."/".$newfilename.".".$path['extension'];

    rename($file, $newfile);    
    update_attached_file( $post_ID, $newfile );

}
```

Reference 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_attached_file
http://wordpress.org/tags/add_attachment

Comment: This breaks the thumbnail previews in the WP dashboard.