# Add suffix to filename of uploaded images

Tags: uploads, attachments, images

I registered 3 custom image sizes (Double sized, for retina displays) with add_image_size: thumbnail@2x, medium@2x and large@2x.

```
function retina_image_sizes() {
    $retina_sizes = array(
        'thumbnail@2x' => array(
        'width' => get_option( 'thumbnail_size_w' ) * 2,
        'height' => get_option( 'thumbnail_size_h' ) * 2,
        'crop' => get_option('thumbnail_crop'),
        ),
        'medium@2x' => array(
        'width' => get_option( 'medium_size_w' ) * 2,
        'height' => get_option( 'medium_size_h' ) * 2,
        'crop' => false,
        ),
        'large@2x' => array(
            'width' => get_option( 'large_size_w' ) * 2,
            'height' => get_option( 'large_size_h' ) * 2,
            'crop' => false,
        )
    );

    foreach ( $retina_sizes as $name => $data ) {
        add_image_size( $name, $data['width'], $data['height'], $data['crop'] );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'retina_image_sizes');
```

Wordpress's naming convention is filename-width x height.jpg. But I need them to be named in another fashion ( filename-originalwidth x originalheight@2x.jpg)

If I upload a picture, and the thumbnail has a size of 100x100, for example, I want the images to be named:

```
example-100x100.jpg
and
example-100x100@2x.jpg
```

I found ways to process pictures and save them under another name, but that is too much. This [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30313/change-attachment-filename) explains, how to change the filename, but, not how to include with and height information. I tried to get it to work, but I only get a single file instead of seven and it throws some errors (probably because it tries to overwrite the file).

How can I change the filename in the above described fashion? Is the add_attachment hook the right one?

Comment: The link and code in the other question is quite good. But it's sadly not complete. There's the `edit_attachment` as well as the `add_attachment` hook which should get considered. When you already queried a file, you can simply use the native PHP function `filesize()` to extract the exact size. The rest can be done via a global or via the function `get_intermediate_image_size()`. Sadly it doesn't give you anything you want. I already proposed a change (incl. patch) some time ago [on WordPress Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18947).

Comment: filesize() returns the files size in byte. I'm talking about width and height.

Comment: Ehm, yeah. Meant `getimagesize()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it in a different way. I just had to update the code from [Gerasimos Tsiamalos Retina Plugin](http://www.cssigniter.com/ignite/retina-images-for-wordpress/) to Wordpress 3.5., using image editor instead of image resize.

This is how it looks like:

```
function nothing_image_make_retina_size($file, $width, $height, $crop=false) {
    if ( $width || $height ) {
        $resized_file = wp_get_image_editor($file);
        if ( ! is_wp_error( $resized_file ) ) {
            $resized_file->resize( $width*2, $height*2, $crop );
            $filename = $resized_file->generate_filename( $width . 'x' . $height . '@2x'  );
            $resized_file->save($filename);
        }
        if ( !is_wp_error($resized_file) && $resized_file && $info = getimagesize($filename) ) {
            $filename = apply_filters('nothing_retina_image_make_intermediate_size', $filename);
            return array(
                'file' => wp_basename( $filename ),
                'width' => $info[0],
                'height' => $info[1],
            );
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function nothing_generate_retina_image_metadata( $metadata, $attachment_id ) {
    $attachment = get_post( $attachment_id );   
    $file = get_attached_file($attachment_id);
    $old_metadata = $metadata;
    foreach ($metadata as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            foreach ($v as $key => $val) {
                if (is_array($val)) {
                    nothing_image_make_retina_size($file, $val['width'], $val['height'], true);
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }
    return $old_metadata;
}
add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'nothing_generate_retina_image_metadata', 10, 2);

function nothing_delete_retina_images( $attachment_id ) {
    $nothing_metas = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id );
    $nothing_updir = wp_upload_dir();
    $nothing_path = pathinfo($nothing_metas['file']);
    $nothing_path_name = $nothing_path['dirname'];
    $nothing_updir = wp_upload_dir();
    foreach ($nothing_metas as $nothing_meta => $nothing_meta_val) {
        if ($nothing_meta === "sizes") {
            foreach ($nothing_meta_val as $nothing_sizes => $nothing_size) {
                $nothing_original_filename = $nothing_updir['basedir'] . "/" . $nothing_path_name . "/" . $nothing_size['file'];
                $nothing_x2_filename = substr_replace($nothing_original_filename, "@2x.", strrpos($nothing_original_filename, "."), strlen("."));
                if (file_exists($nothing_x2_filename)) {
                    unlink($nothing_x2_filename);
                }
            }           
        }       
    }
}
add_filter('delete_attachment','nothing_delete_retina_images');
```