# Add suffix to uploaded images

Tags: images

I found [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102420/add-suffix-to-filename-of-uploaded-images) what handles in a similar way my intention.
But I´m not 100% sure how to expand the callback function with my options.

So here my suit:

I add an function to the functions.php to add some custom imagesizes.

```
    if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {

    add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb1', 900, 9999 );
    add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb2', 500, 9999 );
    add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb3', 250, 9999 );
}
```

How can I add a add a specific suffix to this three images like this:
For "homepage-thumb1" an -medium.jpeg, for "homepage-thumb2" an -small.jpeg and so on.

I know that I can execute an callback function with add_filter.
But how can I add an suffix to an image?

Kind of behavior like this:
if "homepage-thumb1" add suffix "-medium"