# Rename attachment filenames to attachment ID on upload

Tags: uploads, attachments

I have been trying this code out (based on this [Change attachment filename](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30313/change-attachment-filename) ), it does not work properly. For instance, featured image is not being displayed in admin panel single post, neither are being created and uploaded all WordPress re-scaled sizes (as in media settings).

Could someone try this out in order to confirm (me using latest WP version) or could someone   give a fix ?

Thank you !

```
add_action('add_attachment', 'rename_attacment');
function rename_attacment($post_ID){

    $post = get_post($post_ID);
    $file = get_attached_file($post_ID);
    $path = pathinfo($file);
        //dirname   = File Path
        //basename  = Filename.Extension
        //extension = Extension
        //filename  = Filename

    $newfilename = "{$post_ID}";
    $newfile = $path['dirname']."/".$newfilename.".".$path['extension'];

    rename($file, $newfile);    
    update_attached_file( $post_ID, $newfile );

}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?