# How to rename an image attachment filename using php

Tags: images, media-library

I have the ID of the image uploaded and I need to rename it using php.

*(The reasons because I have to do it are difficult to explain and I think they are not even necessary for the purposes of this discussion)*

I have 4 problems to solve:

1. Rename the main **file.jpg** and the related **file-WIDTH-HEIGHT.jpg** files - simply solved with [rename php function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)
2. Re-assign the new filename to the attachment so that WordPress knows the new filename *(can I do it updating the 'guid' column of the attachment in the db?)*
3. Manage the related files (file-WIDTH-HEIGHT.jpg). Where are stored the relationship between the main file and the related ones?
4. Update all these on posts/widget/ecc. *(can I do it with a 'simple' string replace procedure on the sql file exported from the database?)*

As you can see I have a bit of confusion in my mind because I don't know completely the way used by WordPress to manage the attachments from a system/db point of view.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: there are a few built-in function which allow the updating of images, i invite you to check out http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30313/change-attachment-filename

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go and see. If I take arbitrary attachment in my dev install and dump its post object and custom fields I get the following:

```
object WP_Post (24) {
    public ID -> integer 1687
    public post_author -> string (1) "1"
    public post_date -> string (19) "2013-09-18 14:37:07"
    public post_date_gmt -> string (19) "2013-09-18 21:37:07"
    public post_content -> string (0) ""
    public post_title -> string (24) "dsc20050604_133440_34211"
    public post_excerpt -> string (0) ""
    public post_status -> string (7) "inherit"
    public comment_status -> string (4) "open"
    public ping_status -> string (6) "closed"
    public post_password -> string (0) ""
    public post_name -> string (24) "dsc20050604_133440_34211"
    public to_ping -> string (0) ""
    public pinged -> string (0) ""
    public post_modified -> string (19) "2013-09-18 14:37:07"
    public post_modified_gmt -> string (19) "2013-09-18 21:37:07"
    public post_content_filtered -> string (0) ""
    public post_parent -> integer 0
    public guid -> string (76) "http://dev.rarst.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/dsc20050604_133440_34211.jpg"
    public menu_order -> integer 0
    public post_type -> string (10) "attachment"
    public post_mime_type -> string (10) "image/jpeg"
    public comment_count -> string (1) "0"
    public filter -> string (3) "raw"
}

array(2) [
    '_wp_attached_file' => array(1) [
        string (36) "2013/09/dsc20050604_133440_34211.jpg"
    ]
    '_wp_attachment_metadata' => array(1) [
        string (687) "a:5:{s:5:"width";i:640;s:6:"height";i:480;s:4:"file";s:36:"2013/09/dsc20050604_133440_34211.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:2:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:36:"dsc20050604_133440_34211-150x150.jpg";s:5:"width";i:150;s:6:"height";i:150;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:6:"medium";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:36:"dsc20050604_133440_34211-300x225.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:225;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}}s:10:"image_meta";a:10:{s:8:"aperture";d:2;s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:9:"CYBERSHOT";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";i:1117892080;s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";s:3:"9.7";s:3:"iso";s:3:"100";s:13:"shutter_speed";s:6:"0.0125";s:5:"title";s:0:"";}}"
    ]
]
```

The takeaways are respectively to your questions:

2. The `guid` field does **not** matter, it holds a copy of calculated URL (yet it's not *supposed* to be reliable URL in WP context), most of the time it should be ignored.
3. The relationship between main file and sizes is stored in custom meta fields.
4. Simple replace will **not** work, it will ruin serialized string in `_wp_attachment_metadata` meta field. You need serialize–aware search/replace tool, there are quite a few around (WP CLI, Search Replace DB, etc).

Comment: Thank you for the illuminating answer! I'll think about the serialize problem in order to come out with a sort of solution.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Are there any built-in WP functions which can update the _wp_attachment_metadata?

Comment: Hi @RobertSinclair, maybe the function [update_metadata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_metadata) is what you are looking for (I didn't tested it).