# Change WP attachment name to postid during upload only for post type

Tags: functions

I know there is many solutions how to rename attachment while upload files to postid. I got correct solutions that really works fine is: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/30767/86517 ***(I'm new and I can't comments there. So I ask this question.)***

**The code is:**

```
add_action('add_attachment', 'rename_attacment');
function rename_attacment($post_ID){

    $post = get_post($post_ID);
    $file = get_attached_file($post_ID);
    $path = pathinfo($file);
        //dirname   = File Path
        //basename  = Filename.Extension
        //extension = Extension
        //filename  = Filename

    $newfilename = "NEW FILE NAME HERE";
    $newfile = $path['dirname']."/".$newfilename.".".$path['extension'];

    rename($file, $newfile);    
    update_attached_file( $post_ID, $newfile );

}
```

But Problem is, I want this changes only for 3 custom post types. 
Currently my site have 6 custom post type. So Only 3 custom post type need this. There is any way to allow to run this function only for those custom post type?

Thanks

Comment: There is a way, but where do you have this code?

Comment: I got it. I added if ( get_post_type( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) === 'post_type_1' OR get_post_type( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) === 'post_type_2'){} this function and its work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really sorry. I fixed my problem after few minutes I post this question. So I added my working code here for future help if anyone need this.

```
add_action('add_attachment', 'rename_attacment');

function rename_attacment($post_ID){
 if ( get_post_type( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) === 'post_type_1' OR get_post_type( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) === 'post_type_2' OR get_post_type( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) === 'post_type_3' ){
    $post = get_post($post_ID);
    $file = get_attached_file($post_ID);
    $path = pathinfo($file);
        //dirname   = File Path
        //basename  = Filename.Extension
        //extension = Extension
        //filename  = Filename

    $newfilename = "NEW FILE NAME HERE";
    $newfile = $path['dirname']."/".$newfilename.".".$path['extension'];

    rename($file, $newfile);    
    update_attached_file( $post_ID, $newfile );
 }
}
```

Thanks to Everyone.

Comment: Instead of `$_REQUEST['post_id']` why not just use `$post_ID`?

Comment: sorry. only $post_ID is not work for me. Only $_REQUEST['post_id'] is work.

Comment: @czerspalace `$post_ID` is the ID of attachment, not the current post.

Comment: Pretty sure this results in missing thumbnails in the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

More simple & developer friendly code

```
add_action('add_attachment', 'rename_attacment');
    function rename_attacment($post_ID){

    //get post type
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_ID);

    //if not in allowed post types then return
    $allowed_post_types = array('post_1','post_2','post_3');
    if(!in_array($post_type,$allowed_post_types)){
      return;
    }

        $post = get_post($post_ID);
        $file = get_attached_file($post_ID);
        $path = pathinfo($file);
            //dirname   = File Path
            //basename  = Filename.Extension
            //extension = Extension
            //filename  = Filename

        $newfilename = "NEW FILE NAME HERE";
        $newfile = $path['dirname']."/".$newfilename.".".$path['extension'];

        rename($file, $newfile);    
        update_attached_file( $post_ID, $newfile );

    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately file name not update or rename this method. I also tried to use only $post_ID instead of $_REQUEST['post_id'] . Only $_REQUEST['post_id'] method is work for me.