# Rename file after title , one small problem

Tags: functions, uploads, title, get-the-title

I'm using this question: [Change Attachment Filename](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30313/change-attachment-filename) which works but it has a problem.

He renames every file with `FileNameToRename` and it's same image. What I want to do is instead of `FileNameToRename` I want to rename it to the Post Title. Is that possible ?

```
add_action('add_attachment', 'rename_attacment');
function rename_attacment($post_ID){

    $post = get_post($post_ID);
    $file = get_attached_file($post_ID);
    $path = pathinfo($file);
        //dirname   = File Path
        //basename  = Filename.Extension
        //extension = Extension
        //filename  = Filename

    $newfilename = "FileNameToRename";
    $newfile = $path['dirname']."/".$newfilename.".".$path['extension'];

    rename($file, $newfile);    
    update_attached_file( $post_ID, $newfile );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) since you're already being passed a post ID.

```
function rename_attacment( $post_ID ) {
    $post = get_post( $post_ID );
    $file = get_attached_file( $post_ID );
    $path = pathinfo( $file );
        //dirname   = File Path
        //basename  = Filename.Extension
        //extension = Extension
        //filename  = Filename

    $newfilename = get_the_title( $post_ID );
    $newfile = $path['dirname'] . "/" . $newfilename . "." . $path['extension'];

    rename( $file, $newfile );    
    update_attached_file( $post_ID, $newfile );
}
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'rename_attacment' );
```

I'm not sure this will work as you expect it to though. From my understanding, WordPress considers Attachments to be similar to Posts and Pages and will treat the name as duplicate.

For example, if you have a Page called `Test` and you rename the attachment to `Test` WordPress will realize that the title is a duplicate and change it to `Test-1` so that it doesn't confuse the two.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Howdy , I try the code like this and with some tweaks and don't work but i find a plugin that renames directly uploaded file , with date and post title but post title don't work so i take a look on plugin and i think this code has some problems ? if(isset($fileRenamingOptions['post_title_renaming'])){
            $postSlug = $this->getPostSlug();
            if($postSlug!=''){
                $finalFileName = $postSlug;
            }
        }   Maybe this function is deprecated ..old , i don't know

Comment: ahh btw the plugin is no longer updated from 2 years .. so i can't speak with author.